# Fetch results from database with mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to fetch results from database with mysqli prepared statements and I wanted to store it in session, but I failed. I want to store id, username, password and mail to session. Can anyone review my code?

```
$kveri = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$kveri->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$kveri->execute();

$kveri->store_result();
$numrows = $kveri->num_rows;

if ( $numrows == 1 )
  {        
     $kveri->bind_result($user_id, $user_username, $user_password, $user_mail);

     while ( $kveri->fetch() )
       {  
         $_SESSION['ulogovan'] = true;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $user_username;
       }

     $kveri->close();

     echo $_SESSION['username'];
  }
```

Comment: You need to bind the values of username and password to your prepared statement before executing the select

Comment: I edited my code now, i didn't copy it properly... The same thing again

Comment: Do you have the error message, or could you place some markers, and try to find what line it's failing on?

Comment: How did you fail?  Did you get an error?  What was it?  Did you get incorrect results?  What were they and why were they incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have turned on error reporting as follows:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

You are likely to get the answer there. I ran your code flawlessly and it should work.

Note, I added the following code to the beginning to test (with constants defined but not shown here):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Why bother with second code if you already used mysqli_report?

Comment: After code is debugged, I don't use `mysqli_report`, but I would leave the `mysqli_connect_errno` in place for production, ableit with different messaging.

Comment: That just makes no sense. You are making it upside-down. Your mysqli_connect_errno code is just INACCEPTABLE for the production, while mysqli_report is all right. Not to mention that there is no such thing like "code is debugged"

Comment: I wasn't aware that mysqli_connect_errno was not for production while `mysqli_report` is the preferred way to go. I will look into this and modify the post. Regarding `code is debugged`, I often use `var_dump` while debugging to show me what is happening. I do use special code for debugging - perhaps your methods are more universal.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works, the problem was in output :)

Comment: it is not function itself but the way you are using it. you are printing mysqli_connect_errno right in the browser which is obviously forbidden in production.

Comment: Got it. The `printf()` was a copy/paste from the docs. Personally, I am logging all errors and wanted a generic example for the op.

Comment: I will never in my life understand why PHP users want to write SO SO SO SO MUCH CODE.For the every little thing. For the connection. for the execution. for the logging, for th e debugging. And then rewrite it when they switch from logging to debugging. and then rewrite it again when switching back. While all they need is one single line with mysqli report, which will serve them well in any mode with every case

Comment: And they never hesitate to give each other an advise with "regular" code, no matter if it should never be used.

Comment: when in debugging mode you have to have error reporting on. So you will see all the errors from mysqli_report, without a single line of extra code. When in production, you have to set error logging on for the whole PHP with log_errors setting. And again errors will be logged without a single line of extra code. With just two PHP ini settings you can control error messages most flexible and secure way. Without the need of writing any extra code

Comment: FYI, I was quoting the docs as found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.mysqli-report.php) in terms of using both `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` and `if (mysqli_connect_errno())` Using `if (mysqli_connect_errno())` allows for logic branching with errors. Branching with `mysqli_report` doesn't seem as straight forward.

Comment: You don't need branching with errors. When allowed, PHP user would always use it wrong way, just like with this connect example. So - better let PHP itself handle the error, without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, mysqli is quite inconvenient, if used as is. Thousand tricks, nuances and pitfalls.
To make database interactions feasible, one have to use some sort of higher level abstraction, which will undertake all the repeated dirty job.

Out of such abstractions PDO seems most conventional one:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $password]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
if ($user) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
}
```

see - when used wisely, a code not necessarily have to be of the size of "War and Peace"

Comment: You are connecting to mysql, to be strict. And you can do it using PDO as well

Comment: i want to solve this using mysqli prepared statements but not PDO, i don't understand you very well.

Comment: There is no reason for such a whim. But if you want to - it's up to you, go on with mysqli.

Comment: i'm using mysqli prepared statements all over my code, and i can't change that so i wan't to solve this with mysqli not pdo...

Comment: Well, I am sure you don't have too much code yet. Anyway, there are already more than thousand answers to your question.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to solve it and thank you on wasting your time on my problems :)